# intervention/image fail to download

Tags: laravel, doctrine, laravel-5, intervention

When typed "composer require intervention/image", received the following error:

```
Problem 1
    - doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.38) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.38) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for doctrine/inflector (installed at v1.2.0) -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.2.0].
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this? Or other better ways to deal with image uploads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Installation request for doctrine/inflector` means `intervention/image` required `doctrine/inflector` so it have to be install.

But in order to install `doctrine/inflector` you need PHP version `7.0` and since you're on PHP version `5.5.38` this requirement failed and the installation can not continue.

You need to upgrade to PHP `7.0`